# TinyMCE: when selecting Bold, how to use different font instead of applying normal bold style?

Tags: fonts, tinymce, tinymce-4

When I select Bold in TinyMCE I want to make it use a different font instead of just using the bold variant of current font - how can I do that?

Comment: You would need to create your own custom toolbar button to do this ... the bold button does just that (bolds text) ... what you are requesting is not bolding text.  Here is a simple example of how to add a custom toolbar button:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-button/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// get the current editor
var editor = tinyMce.activeEditor;

// get the editor formatter
var f = editor.formatter;

f.register('customBold', {
    inline: 'span',
    selector: 'span,p',
    styles: { fontWeight: 'bold',fontFamily: 'arial'.....your custom style },
});

editor.addCommand('customBold',function(){
    editor.applyFormat(name)
});

// add a button in the toolbar
editor.addButton(customBtn, {
    tooltip: 'My custom bold',
    icon: 'bold',
    cmd: customBold
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code of your **bold** text, it could be marked

```
<strong>, <b>, <span style="*"> or else
```

depending on the settings of your Tiny Instance.

When you know this, you should be able to set the font in the editor stylesheet.

For example

```
p strong{
  font-weight:400;
  font-family: ...;
}
```