# Tinymce make bold first 140 characters

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I'm using `TinyMCE` for my project, and I want to make the first 140 characters that type the user be bold, anyone made something similar?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. There is likely some documentation or links in google if you search for bold tinymce

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739352/tinymce-when-selecting-bold-how-to-use-different-font-instead-of-applying-norm

Comment: Thanks, but I think I do not explain, what I want is that the first 140 characters are bold but without the user having to press the bold button, so the user is forced to leave bold the first 140 characters

Comment: You should show what you have attempt in your coding environment and someone will be more able to offer help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested code

```
tinyMCE.init({
  setup : function(ed){
    ed.on('NodeChange', function(e){ 
      var text = ed.getContent().replace(/<b>/g,"").replace(/<\\b>/g,"");
      ed.setContent('<b>'+text.substring(0,140)+'</b>'+text.substring(140));
    }
  }
}
```